# How to make a fixed menu/sidebar while using position:relative?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, fixed

I want to make an relative div that can be scrolled down until it reaches the top of the page, then the div should be fixed and stay on top until page is scrolled up again. Perhaps I should use jquery?!

These are my code. **The div called: .sidebar is the one I want to have fixed while scrolling!** I have shown more divs and css styles to show you guys how it is. This is how it looks like: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img841/5807/pjpj.png

```
<div id="header" class="container">

<div id="navbar">


        <div id="menu">
            <ul><h2>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="3" title="contact">contact</a></li>
                <li><img src="images/icon_triangle.jpg"></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html" accesskey="4" title="portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
                <li><img src="images/icon_triangle.jpg"></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="5" title="about">about</a></li>
                <li><img src="images/icon_triangle.jpg"></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="6" title="home">home</a></li>
                </h2>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="content">

<h7>HappyDays</h7><br /><br />
<h5>Webdesign</h5>
<h4>Made in Photo</h4><br /><br />
<h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempor mattis ornare. Ut semper sem nec justo adipiscing ullamcorper. Nullam sit amet lacus et arcu vestibulum volutpat. Cras mi lectus, consequat quis pretium eu, sodales vitae velit. Donec imperdiet quis urna at egestas. Curabitur in libero commodo est hendrerit condimentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut posuere, purus nec convallis lobortis, neque est ornare felis, ut iaculis nulla erat sed diam. Cras non leo libero.</p></h4><br /><br />  


<a rel="prettyPhoto" href="images/cocktail.jpg"><img src="images/images/cocktail.jpg" style="width: 50%; float: left;"></a>



</div>



<div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html" accesskey="3"><img src="images/icon_triangle_all.jpg" width="80%"><br /><br /><h6>All</h6></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="portfolio"><img src="images/icon_triangle_previous.jpg"  width="30%"><br /><br /><h6>Previous</h6></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="5"><img src="images/icon_triangle_next.jpg"  width="50%"><br /><br /><h6>Next</h6></a></li>
            </ul>
<div class="line2"></div>
 </div>
```

**NOW THE CSS!**

```
#menu
    {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 13em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0.5%;
    width: 50%;
    word-spacing:30px;
    z-index:999;
    }




#navbar 
    {
        background:#fff;
        height:5%;
        width:100%;
        bottom: auto !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
        z-index:999;

        }
 #content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
   position: relative;  
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
     width: 66.667%;

 }

.sidebar    
    {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    width: 50%;
    z-index:999;    
    text-decoration:none;


    }

    .sidebar li {

    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
     -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out;

    }
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle link?

Comment: My jsfiddle link didn't work. Don't know why I can post it. But I want to have it exactly as here. See the side menu: http://fixate.it/portfolio/hugo-orthodontics/#main

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ce8n9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the devs from the site you linked to, Fixate.

Currently, some implementation of jQuery will be the best choice. This is a tricky problem to solve - you need a good understanding of both JS and CSS layout fundamentals.

There is a `position: sticky;` property which will allow you to do this [once all browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky). Filament group have a [polyfill](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky) which may be useful, although I'm not sure how well it behaves on responsive items.

Until then, you'll have to go with one of the following:

**1.** Hard-code values in your js, as @manu showed.

**2.** Use a dynamic approach with a plugin.

### jQuery stickToTop (shameless plug)

We built a jQuery plugin, [jQuery sticktotop](https://github.com/sdbondi/JQuery-StickToTop), which solves the problem without you having to know the scroll height.

As an example, include it after jQuery, and then initialise stickToTop in your main js file, or in a script tag on your page:

```
// make the element with the class .js-sticky-menu sticky if window is > 480px
$('.js-sticky-menu').stickToTop({minWindowWidth: 480);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://sdbondi.github.io/jquery-sticktotop/sidebar-offset.html)

### jQuery Pin

On our site, we used a plugin called [jquery pin](http://webpop.github.io/jquery.pin/), as there were a few issues with our plugin at the time. Some of those issues have been cleared up.

---

One of the advantages of our plugin is that it performs better under resizing (as long as you're not attempting to make a floated div sticky - if you're targeting a float, rather target a div inside the float instead - see [here](http://heaids.org.za.www26.jnb1.host-h.net/about/mission-vision/)). Elements will dynamically resize while sticking.

Jquery pin, on the other hand, will allow you to set a bottom bound dynamically for the sticky element's container.

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing your help! It's very nice to know that your one of the devs from the site Fixate. I have read your comment thoroughly and tried a couple of things but I don't seem to get it completely. So you're saying I must make a div which says float:right (by example) and the main div I want to have 'pinned' don't need to have this code?

Comment: So I make a div in a div. I now have 3 divs: right-col, pin-wrapper and pinned. In right-col I say it must be float:right; in the pin-wrapper I say the height. And pinned has other styles like diplay,z-index,padding..  Then I have javascript called: jquery.pin.js as the demo with the code you gave. Can you help? Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/xbrfP/

Comment: I edited my answer regarding the float - basically, don't target a floated div for sticking. If you're not floating a div, then don't worry about that :) In your fiddle, you haven't loaded any scripts - you need stickToTop in there, and jquery too. I'd recommend visiting this page: http://sdbondi.github.io/jquery-sticktotop/sidebar.html, then viewing the source, particularly, the class on the sidebar, the scripts loaded at the bottom of the page, and the inline javascript after the libraries.

Comment: also, as it seems you may be entirely new to javascript, I'd recommend going through the basics of adding javascript to web pages first: http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html

Comment: Yes I am new with javascript and still beginner with html&css. I have worked with javascript a couple of times, but not really noticing how things really work. But even if i'm reading the tutorial for beginners it isn't really clear to me how to use the sticky. I have found this one: http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/ Now I have changed my divs again like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Y48V2/

I want to use float right. I don't know an other way really..

Comment: Is it possible you speak Dutch? Since you're from Johannesburg? :)

Comment: haha, all I can offer is some terrible Afrikaans :) Your JS paths are not going to work - where it says '/path/to/jquery.js' they expect you to update that for the location of your project's scripts on your own computer. My previous link will explain how to add scripts to a webpage. Make sure you understand how to add scripts first, otherwise you won't get other libraries working! I have made a jsfiddle with sticktotop, here: http://jsfiddle.net/6we24/, and also a codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/scfjG (codepen is great for live editing)

Comment: Okay, I understand how to link the jquery in the HTML. I just don't know where to download this link: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js .. If I have the link it will work haha. I'm glad you helped me 'cause the jsfiddle you gave with your explanation was very clear.

Comment: you can download jquery from their site: http://jquery.com/download/. What I did there was use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) to deliver the script. Don't worry about that for now, download jquery, and then happy coding :)

Comment: Still not happy coding here, I downloaded the jQuery 2.1.1, then put it in my file map named: js. My link in HTML is <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> but it doesn't seem to work.. any ideas? :o

Comment: Hi Larry, I just wanted to let you know my code works :). My reaction is late, because I was busy with other things. Now that this problem is solved, I can now make my website online! Thanks for all your information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script which you could use to recreate the sidebar example you showed.

As a start up to help you, this should be enough.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manublueheart/4TfTF/731/)

script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( scrollVal > 150) {
        $('#subnav').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
    } else {
        $('#subnav').css({'position':'static','top':'auto'});
    }
});
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://inkd.klevermedia.co.uk)?

I used Waypoints [sticky elements](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) which works quite well.

Comment: Yes something like that indeed! I want to use it just as the right menu in here: http://fixate.it/portfolio/hugo-orthodontics/#main 

But the code you gave me didn't work.. Im quite new with jquery etc.